# Sum of $\Gamma(n+a) / \Gamma(n+b)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, gamma-function

If $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, such that $b > a + 1$, can we find the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma(n+b)}?$$ 
For example I have found that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+3/2)}{\Gamma(n+3)} = \sqrt{\pi} = \Gamma(1/2)$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+4/3)}{\Gamma(n+4)} = \frac{3}{10}\Gamma(4/3)$$ but no general rule.

Comment: Can you show me where you found those sums?

Comment: @PratyushSarkar I just tried things in WolframAlpha. Some sums don't evaluate, but all the ones I tried were simple expressions in $\Gamma(a)$ and $\Gamma(b)$, like above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recalling the $\beta$ function

> $$ \mathrm{\beta}(x,y) = \int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt ,  $$

we have

$$ \frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma(n+b)} =  \frac{\beta(n+a,b-a)}{\Gamma(b-a)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(b-a)}\int_{0}^{1} t^{n+a-1}(1-t)^{b-a-1}dt   $$

$$ \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma(n+b)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(b-a)}\int_{0}^{1} t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-a-2}dt = \frac{\beta(a,b-a-1)}{\Gamma(b-a)} $$

$$= {\frac {\Gamma  \left( a \right) }{ \left( b-a-1 \right) \Gamma \left( b-1 \right) }}
=  {\frac {(b-1)\Gamma\left( a \right) }{ \left( b-a-1 \right) \Gamma \left( b \right) }}.$$

Answer (score 4):

in general
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma{(a+k)}\Gamma{(b+k)}}{k!\Gamma{(c+k)}}=\dfrac{\Gamma{(a)}\Gamma{(b)}\Gamma{(c-a-b)}}{\Gamma{(c-a)}\Gamma{(c-b)}}$$

note that
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-x)^{-a}dx=B(b,c-a-b)=\dfrac{\Gamma{(b)}\Gamma{(c-a-b)}}{\Gamma{(c-a)}}$$
and we have
$$(1-x)^{-a}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{a-1+k}{k}x^k$$

then 
\begin{align*}I&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{a-1+k}{k}\int_{0}^{1}x^{b+k-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(a-1+k)!}{(a-1)!k!}B(b+k,c-b)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\dfrac{\Gamma{(a+k)}}{\Gamma{(a)}k!}\cdot\dfrac{\Gamma{(b+k)}\Gamma{(c-b)}}{\Gamma{(c+k)}}
\end{align*}
so
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma{(a+k)}\Gamma{(b+k)}}{k!\Gamma{(c+k)}}=\dfrac{\Gamma{(a)}\Gamma{(b)}\Gamma{(c-a-b)}}{\Gamma{(c-a)}\Gamma{(c-b)}}$$

so let $b=1$
then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma{(a+k)}}{\Gamma{(c+k)}}=\dfrac{\Gamma{(a)}\Gamma{(c-a-1)}}{\Gamma{(c-1)}}$$

Comment: The derivation looks really good. I'm worried that it doesn't agree with Mathematica's results, though

Comment: The derivation of the general formula is OK (it is the value for $_2F_1(a,b,c,1)$. The error occurs when setting $b=1$: 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma{(a+k)}}{\Gamma{(c+k)}}=\dfrac{\Gamma{(a)} \Gamma{(c-a-1)}}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma{(c-1)}} =
{\dfrac{(c-1)\Gamma\left( a \right) }{ \left( c-a-1 \right) \Gamma \left( c \right) }}=
{\dfrac{\Gamma\left( a \right) }{ \left( c-a-1 \right) \Gamma \left( c-1 \right) }}
$$