# Question about the value of the Infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried all day long to get the value of the following infinite series..

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^{k}}{{2k+1}\choose {k}}$

which seems to be $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ by my matlab iteration.

Can anyone help me to get this value?

Comment: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928968/summation-of-series-sum-k-0-infty-2k-binom2k1k)